# MVC5 - View does not return the Id of my object on post

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-mvc-5

My view is shown below:

```
@model KtembRegistry.Models.Entities.Member

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Üye Güncelleme";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MemberId)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Director.EmployeeId);

    <div class="form-horizontal">


        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="button" value="Back to List" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Members")'" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MemberName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MemberName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemberName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MemberClass, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MemberClass, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MemberClass, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClassId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClassId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastApprovalDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastApprovalDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastApprovalDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaxNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaxNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TaxNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fax, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fax, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fax, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mobile, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <br />
        <h4>Direktör</h4>
        <hr />

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Director.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Director.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Director.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Director.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Director.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Director.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Director.IdentityNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Director.IdentityNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Director.IdentityNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Director.Responsibility, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Director.Responsibility, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Director.Responsibility, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>


        <br />
        <h3> Personel </h3>
        <hr />


        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>İsim</th>
                    <th>Kimlik No</th>
                    <th>Yetki</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Employees)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.FirstName</td>
                        <td>@item.IdentityNo</td>
                        <td>@item.Responsibility</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { @item.EmployeeId }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { @item.EmployeeId })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>


    </div>


}



@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Entity:

```
   public class Employee
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }

        public virtual int EmployeeNo { get; set; }

        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual int IdentityNo { get; set; }

        public virtual string Responsibility { get; set; }

        public virtual Member Company { get; set; }

    }
```

When I do post, everything is sent to controller just fine except `model.Director.EmployeeId`. The controller sends the `EmployeeId` field correctly to the field. Whatever, I do it does not work. Any ideas why my post does not work ?

Comment: Are you sure, your value is delivered to View before posting?

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure it is delivered

Comment: @MiroslavHolec It's only the ID that is not posted back

Answer (score 0):

I have an old habit of making the setter of identity fields in my entities protected in order to protect outside mangling. However, in this case it was causing the identity field from being updated which was the cause of the problem.

Comment: You should delete your question - there is no mention of you model and its properties so this is of no use to anyone.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can't delete it since there are answers... but I will edit it